# How to get child model having one to one relation with default User model of Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I created a model having one-to-one relation with default `User` model to extend it for providing some permission for tabs in my website. Now I want to not show the tab options to the users not having permissions to access them.

user permission model:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class userpermissions(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
```

Checking whether the user has permission or not I created a function which is supposed to get the `userpermission` model instance of the logged in user. For which I used the following code:

```py
def check(user):
    up = User.userpermissions_set.get(id=user.id)
```

Now when user logs in the login function will call this check function and redirect to the tab that the user can access and also send the **up** variable containing all the permissions of the user so that the Navbar template can hide those tabs which the user has no access to.

Now the problem that I am facing is when I run the server it shows this error:

> AttributeError at /
> type object 'User' has no attribute 'userpermissions_set'

I saw on YouTube that to get the instance of child model (I don't know what to call it) we need to use it's name all in small case with _set (e.g. `parent.child_set.all()`)

As per the error on browser it seems the wrong way to get the child model data (again - I don't know what to call it).

I was expecting to get all child model data but it did not work.